# Magento 2 - Send data into a new quote_item column from an API call

Tags: magento2, cart, api, plugin, preference

I have added a new column in `quote_item` table and want to add this field as a parameter in cart API payload but I don't how this will happen.

This is what I get when i try to hit add to cart api.
Please let me know. I am new in magento development.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add extension attribute for Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface

```
 <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
    <attribute code="custom_feedback" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

create custom field on quote item,

```
<table name="quote_item" resource="default" engine="innodb">
    <column xsi:type="text" name="custom_feedback" nullable="true" comment="Feedback"/>
</table>
```

Add Plugins on Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository
get the extension attribute from cartItem and set the same value to  custom  feedback field on beforeSave method,

```
$extAttributes = $cartItem->getExtensionAttributes();
$cusomFeedback = $extAttributes->getcustomFeedback();
$cartItem->setcustomFeedback($cusomFeedback);
```

sent payload request with extension attribute value as,

```
extension_attrubutes:{
'custom_feedback':'testing item feedback'
}
```

Comment: I have done the same process as per your suggestion but after hitting API it doesn't add value against custom column. But it gives me value against extension attribute when i debug.

Comment: so you are getting extension attribute value and please ensure that $cartItem->setCustomerFeedback value return to that repository plugins

Comment: It's almost working fine but for inserting data I have to add some logic in afterSave method to insert data in quote_item table.

Comment: Thanks. Please ensure its beforeSave or afterSave method.

Comment: Yes i have done it using beforeSave and afterSave method. In beforeSave method, I picked extension attribute and save it in global variable and then in afterSave method I used that global variable and insert it's value in Database. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Okay, Thanks.Is it working as expected for you?. if so please accepted it

Comment: Yes its almost working as expected but I just want to make sure one more thing that when i get cart item then I want to list extension attributes in response of each cart item. I mean i want to list extension attribute in response of add to cart and get cart items.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Firstly, go to the below path

**`app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\extension_attributes.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
  <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface">
        <attribute code="customattribute" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Step 2:** Now go to the below path

**`app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml`**

And add the code as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="cart_extra_attribute" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Cartrepositoryplugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step 3:** Then, move to the below path

**`app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Cartrepositoryplugin.php`**

And add the code as below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin;
 
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
 
class Cartrepositoryplugin
{
    protected $extensionFactory;
 
    public function __construct(CartExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }
     public function afterGet(CartRepositoryInterface $subject, CartInterface $quote)
    {
        $customattribute = $quote->getData('customattribute');
        $extensionAttributes = $quote->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setData('customattribute',$customattribute);
        
        $quote->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $quote;
    }
}
```

Now you add your custom attribute on payload request,

```
extension_attrubutes:{
'customattribute':'Here your value'
}
```

If any queries let me know.

**`Thanks.`**

Comment: Hi, I am still facing issues after doing what you suggested. Column value doesn't add in quote_item table when I hit API with extension attributes. Is there any other table for extension attributes ?